# File.Delete() and File.Rename is ignored

Tags: java, csv, file-io

I'm currently testing the edit method for the CSV file. However, the File.Delete() and File.Rename() is highlighting in yellow and told me that these commands will be ignored. What is the cause of this and how do I fix it?

```
public class Main {

    private static Scanner x;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String filepath = "Leads.csv";
        String editerm = "Lead_000";
        String newID = "Lead_003";
        String newname = "Cac";
    }

    public static void editRecord(String filepath, String editerm, String newID, String newname) {
        String tempfile = "temp.csv;";
        File oldfile = new File(filepath);
        File newfile = new File(tempfile);
        String ID = "";
        String name = "";
        try {
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(tempfile, true);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(bw);
            x = new Scanner(new File(filepath));
            x.useDelimiter("[,\n]");

            while (x.hasNext()) {
                ID = x.next();
                name = x.next();
                if (ID.equals(editerm)) {
                    pw.println(newID + "," + newname);
                } else {
                    pw.println(ID + "," + name);
                }
                x.close();
                pw.flush();
                pw.close();
                oldfile.delete();
                File dump = new File(filepath);
                newfile.renameTo(dump);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess that IDE marks your `File.Delete()` and `File.Rename()` lines.
It says that it will ignore the result of this function because you don't store the return value.

If you want to fix it, you should store the return values

```
boolean result = oldfile.delete();
```